# Visual Studio 2017 Web publishing fails if user is non-admin while the same user can be used for VS2015 web publishing on the same web server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, web-publishing

I am trying to publish a **ASP.NET Core Web project** to IIS (remote server) using a non-admin account using Visual Studio 2017 and I have the following error on deploy:

> Starting Web deployment task from source:
>   manifest(D:\Projects\Own\AspNetCore\CoreWithAngularTrial\CoreWithAngularTrialApi\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\PubTmp\CoreWithAngularTrialApi.SourceManifest.xml)
>   to Destination: auto(). C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(134,5):
>   Error : Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer
>   ("...") using the Web Management Service, but could
>   not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and
>   password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the
>   credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site. 
>   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.)
>   Make sure the site name, user name, and password are correct. If the
>   issue is not resolved, please contact your local or server
>   administrator. Error details: Connected to the remote computer
>   ("...") using the Web Management Service, but could
>   not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and
>   password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the
>   credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site. 
>   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.
>   The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Publish
>   failed to deploy.

I have the following configuration for deployment:

```
Publish method = Web deploy
Server = servername:8172/msdeploy.axd
Site name = Default Web Site/CoreWithAngularTestApi
User name = username
Password = ******
```

The exact same configuration works when publishing a different application (ASP.NET MVC 5) under the same Web site (Default Web Site), so publishing configuration appears to be correct on the remote server.

Making `username` a local administrator unblocks the publishing process in Visual Studio 2017.

Also, publishing configuration files (*.pubxml) are virtually identical.

Event viewer on remote server catches the following error:

> IISWMSVC_AUTHORIZATION_SERVER_NOT_ALLOWED
>
> Only Windows Administrators are allowed to connect using a server
>   connection. Other users should use the 'Connect To Site or
>   Application' task to be able to connect.
>
> Process:WMSvc User=username

**Question:** How can I enabled non-administration web publishing from Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed: https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/issues/146.

ASP.NET core project uses a different set of Publish targets (hence the change in behavior from MVC5). This project is available on GitHub - https://github.com/aspnet/websdk.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out why the publish fails with non-admin user. Server setup is correct, but Visual Studio publishing seems to treat ASP.NET Core Web app deployment differently from ASP.NET MVC 5 one.

I had to explicitly specify web site name within the publishing profile xml file. So, instead of:

```
<MSDeployServiceURL>servername:8172/msdeploy.axd</MSDeployServiceURL>
```

I put

```
<MSDeployServiceURL>servername:8172/msdeploy.axd?Site=Default Web Site</MSDeployServiceURL>
```

NOTE: This problem does not occur when publishing an MVC 5 project within VS2017.